# Ember.js, EmberCLI - removing the hash ( # ) from the URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

So according to [Ember's documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) Ember defaults to using the [hashchange](http://caniuse.com/hashchange) event. Thats why we have the fancy `#/some/url` setup. We can also set it to use the browser's [history](http://caniuse.com/history) API.

I've noticed that most (if not all) sites listed on [Built with Ember](http://builtwithember.io/) apparently use the history API. Which makes sense because it make the URL look more natural.

All that is to say I (sorta) understand where, how, and why the `#` gets tacked on.

My question relates specifically to EmberCLI. I've noticed that when I create a simple app the `#` is not in the URL. Is that because I havent deployed it yet? Or does the CLI default to the history api? If so, where is this set? I cant find an instance of

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

Comment: Does this default hashchange not work on localhost. I mean when using localhost, I do not see any # for the routes in the address bar ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first one I clicked used hash history ;)  https://fnd.io/

By default Ember uses the hash change event, mostly due to cross browser compatibility.  http://caniuse.com/history

In ember-cli it uses `auto` by default.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_autolocation

If you look in `router.js` you'll notice

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: YourAppENV.locationType
});
```

which pulls its settings from `config/environment.js`

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
    ....
```

Just as a quick plug, location history is a tad more difficult to set up, since you 
essentially have to tell your server to serve from the base page whenever it's hit, and ignore anything after that, but it's really just a one time setup.

Comment: touche on the find.io. I clicked a random sample earlier and all of their URLs omitted the #. Not sure what you mean about how I wouldnt be changing routes though

Comment: Good catch on the config. I totally overlooked that. I'll have to find a good article or something talking about the pros and cons of each location type in Ember

Comment: So, I should do more searching before I open my mouth. I found [Ember's documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html) on the `location` api.

Comment: @kingpin2k, Like your comment, it is just a one time setup. I am trying to do that setup, but I stuck on static resource path. Everything is being prefixed with 'moduleName'. Could you look at this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062002/express-node-worked-as-pushstate-enabled-server-serve-any-static-resource-withou)

Answer (score 1):

For `locationType: 'auto'`
Your routes will be `http://localhost:4200/login`

For `locationType: 'hash'`
Your routes will be `http://localhost:4200/#/login`

That's it.