# Express node worked as pushState enabled server serve any static resource without any path prefix

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, ember.js, express, pushstate

I am building a single page web application with Ember.js or Backbone.js as front end MVC, express.js(node.js) as back end server.

*server/app.js* code in short

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client')));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('base'); (will sendFile (client/index.html) )
});
```

It will load up the *client/* folder with all the public assets, client folder structure looks like this

```
- client
   -- index.html ( will be rendered as always )
   -- app (front end mvc code)
   -- assets
      -- images
      -- styles
```

When html5 **pushstate** is enabled by front end MVC, express server is always serving all the matching route as well, which in turn render index.html as always when page is refreshed or url is being manually inserted in the browser.

*client/index.html* (sample code)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/base.css">
```

Here are three different URLs cases

```
localhost:3000/        (root)
localhost:3000/users  || localhost:3000/#/users (hard url)
localhost:3000/users/1    || localhost:3000/#/users/1  ( dynamic segment)
```

When I defined any static resource as relative path, it works on matching path with root url and hard url on page refresh, it serves resources as

```
GET /assets/styles/reset.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/styles/base.css 304 2ms
```

But when I got to `localhost:3000/users/1` and refresh the page, I got the wrong resource url, so it failed on loading `client/index.html` since there are no resources in that path.

```
GET /users/assets/styles/reset.css 304 2ms
GET /users/assets/styles/base.css 304 6ms
```

Then I switched to absolute path in
*client/index.html* (sample code)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/base.css">
```

it works well even in the dynamic segment url `localhost:3000/users/1`, all resource serve in the correct url path. but I have an html `img` tag `<img src="assets/images/icons/star.png" alt="star">` in front end mvc template which will be rendered when application boots up. When I load up `localhost:3000/users/1` on page refresh, here is what I get

```
GET /assets/styles/reset.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/styles/base.css 304 2ms
GET /users/assets/images/icons/star.png 304 5ms
```

I tried with absolute path and relative path in front end mvc template (`<img src="/assets/images/icons/star.png" alt="star">`), it loads with `users` prefix no matter what.

I found a solution by [tbranyen](https://gist.github.com/tbranyen/1359650), but it did not quite work for me. I do not need to setup any cluster at all, what I want is my express server to serve any resource without any prefix when any dynamic segment is being matched. So I wrote this middleware, and it fires correct but still loads the static resource with `users/` prefix.

```
// this route uses the ":user" named parameter
// which will cause the 'user' param callback to be triggered
router.get('/users/:user_id', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('req.params: ', req.params.user_id );
  //console.log('@TODO: need to handle the params here');
  //next();
  return res.render('base');
});
```

Problem:

When using Express.js as a server, I want every browser request will be handled with response `client/index.html`, even with dynamic query segment. Currently, whenever url query involves with dynamic query segment `/users/:user_id`, the response from express server will prefix with `users` to all the static resources.

For example, when I load the url with dynamic segment `localhost:3000/users/1`. if i have a resources `assets/images/icons/star.png` in handlebars template, express server response back `/users/assets/images/icons/star.png`, but I do not have `users` folder with the assets. What I want response back `/assets/images/icons/star.png`.

I tried with absolute path `/assets/images/icons/star.png` or relative path `assets/images/icons/star.png` in the handlebars template, it always return with `users` prefix in the response.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would probably help if you included a section to TLDR your problem at the top or bottom. I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: @JoshWillik I have updated with the problem at the bottom. Let me know if it is not clear to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `<head>` of your base template, add this toward the top:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: It works great. Thanks. It was implemented in ember-cli and cannot believe that I missed it.

Comment: Thanks @JoshWillik, however if you want him to get notified of your comment you'll have to tag him like I did with your username in this commnt.

Comment: @MMA Please see the above