# ember baseUrl duplication

Tags: spring, ember.js

I have a `Spring` based backend, and an `ember` single page app that is served roughly as described here:

[Ember.js, EmberCLI - removing the hash ( # ) from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028330/ember-js-embercli-removing-the-hash-from-the-url)

The dispatching servlet is mapped to serve from `/foo`.

The production `env` config is the following:

```
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.baseUrl = '/foo/';
  ENV.locationType = 'auto';
}
```

Although the dispatching works, the url is duplicated. When i try to visit `/foo/account`, I'm ending with `/foo/foo/account`.

Comment: Could you please share your router.js? Maybe you already declare there `foo/`. `Roter.map(function() {
  this.route('foo', function() {
    this.route('account');
  });
});`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot share my router.js but I can assure you that there is no such thing as a `foo` route. :)

This issue is also mentioned here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4905#issuecomment-155713312

Comment: Ah, ok... so you are using v1.13.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our `router.js` had the following entry which was causing the problem:

```
const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  rootURL: config.baseURL,
  ...
)}
```

removing it resolves this issue.